# auth0 User token for Regular Web Application

Tags: java, jwt, postman, token, auth0

I have a jhipster generated monolithic application with Java bakend and React Frontend.
Now I am building up the api (backend) and want to test the endpoints with postman.

Too access protected ressources for example access only allwod with role USER, so I need to pass the acces token in the Authorizations Header of the request in Postman.

How can I get such a User Token from auth0 to put that token into Postman?

I tried to find answer but was not able to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an access token using Auth0's CLI:

```bash
auth0 test token -a https://<your-auth0-domain>/api/v2/
```